# Programmatically choosing which variables to put into dplyr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning, tidyverse

I'm working with datasets (from smartphone experience sampling) where I have to very frequently performed grouped operations (such as find the variability of a measure within each person, or within each day within each person, etc). Typical code might look like the code below, which calculates within-day variability for some variables, then takes the mean of the within-day variability and joins it to the original data.

```
output <- group_by(mydata, id, day) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(angr, sad, guil, anx, hap), funs(sd(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(angr, sad, guil, anx, hap), funs('var_day_mean' = mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  join(mydata, .)
```

What I want to do is be able to save this as a function so that instead of having to type out `angr, sad, guil, anx, hap` many times over, I can call this code (and slight variations on it saved as different functions) on a vector of variable names in a string. So the desired functionality is:

```
vars <- c('angr', 'sad', 'guil', 'anx', 'hap')

output <- myfunc(vars)
```

Where myfunc performs the piped operations above.

I'm aware that there is a vignette for non standard evaluation using dplyr but it's very limited and doesn't cover mutate or most of what I need to do with this use case, so would appreciate any insight.

Reproducible example - what I desire is essentially that the below code work, but currently the dplyr pipe cannot take vars as a character vector the way I have input it.

Edit: I was mistaken - the below code does work, and dplyr can function in this way (and can also take character vectors to group_by, making this easy to program with). I leave the code below as a (working) reference.

```
data <- data.frame('ID' = rep(1:10, each = 10), 
                   'day' = rep(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 10), 
                   'anx' = rnorm(100), 'sad' = rnorm(100), 'hap' = rnorm(100))

vars = c('anx', 'sad', 'hap')

out <- group_by(data, ID, day) %>%
  mutate_at(vars, funs(sd(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Try with `summarise_at(one_of(vars), funs(..`  Please show a reproducible example for others to test your code

Comment: That's very helpful - I hadn't seen one_of. But it appears only to work with select, and doesn't seem to work the way you suggest (when nested within summarise_at or mutate_at). I can still get my intended workflow to run this way by selecting and then switching to summarise_all. But am I missing something?

I can try to put together a reproducible example, it will just take a while to generate some data.

Comment: I have put together a minimal reproducible example, which will hopefully be helpful.

Comment: Your code is working for me.  I am using the devel version i.e. `data %>% group_by(ID, day) %>% mutate_at(vars, funs(sd(., na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: Your code (at the bottom) works for me on the CRAN version too (v0.5.0). Otherwise try `summarise_at(vars(one_of(vars)), funs(..`

Comment: You guys are right - I hadn't actually tried to run it the way I wrote in my reproducible code before posting this! I'd been trying more complicated answers because this hadn't worked for me in earlier versions (before mutate_at and summarise_at were implemented).


I guess this is a much easier problem than I thought now. I'll leave the question up for others' reference, since I couldn't find this answer easily. Thanks a lot to you both for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `mutate_at` you can simply supply the names of the columns as a vector:

```
mtcars %>% mutate_at(c("mpg", "hp"), funs(mean))
```

This should do the trick.